# view a Document at one specific point in time? (dup, versioning?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Mongoid - 2.4.7

I need to store a copy of a Document at a particular point in time.

- I'll know the exact point in time
- they'll happen manually (defined like an expiration date)
- and will only happen once or twice over life of the document.

What's the best way to do this?

**Separate Model(s)** - Create separate ExpiredWhatever Models and copy the records when they "expire"? That feels a little gross, especially considering the parent has embedded docs, which also has an embedded docs.

**Versioning** - The built in Mongoid Versioning could work, but I don't need a version stored on every update, only at 1 or 2 particular points in time.  So I'd need to be able to *manually* set this.

(Also this Parent Document is actually embedded itself; however, that could change as I know Mongoid::Versioning doesn't work with embedded docs.)

So, what's the best way to view a Document (and its embedded docs) at a specific point in time?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually do this. I would create another key in the parent document named or prior_version or snapshot_version and store the copy there.

You will need to test to see how mongoid handles that assignment and possibly perform a manual deep copy as you have many embedded fields/docs.

I think separate models is overkill and versioning won't work for this application (as you said, you only need one copy)

Answer (score 0):

From the Mongoid docs on Versioning:

> You may skip versioning at any point in time by wrapping the persistence call in a versionless block.

```
person.versionless do |doc|
  doc.update_attributes(name: "Theodore")
end
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but you can have an if statement that switches from versioned to versionless when you want it to. Ie, save versionless most of the time, but when you set a flag, the if statement switches to the versioned save.